# php remove string: fa fa-phone famouse

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to remove the strings **fa** and **fa-phone** of the string: "fa famouse fa-phone".

I tried:

```
preg_replace('/fa.+$/','', 'fa famouse fa-phone');
```

But now it removes all strings with `fa`.

Comment: `/\bfa(-phone)?\b/`. The word `fa` optionally followed by `-phone`. The `\b` boundaries make sure it isn't `fa` as part of another word as in `famouse`. You would likely also want to remove spaces so trim the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/fa[ \-](phone)?/','','fa famouse fa-phone');
```

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/bJ3nE7/1

---

`fa` (literal)
`[ \-]` match a space or a hyphen
`(phone)?`  match the literal 'phone' 0 or 1 times

Answer (score 0):

> So i want to remove the string fa and all the strings a beginning with fa-
>   But not other strings that contain fa like famouse for example.

Here is a way to do the job:

```
echo preg_replace('/fa(?:-[-\w]+|\b)/', '', 'fa famouse fa-phone-small fabrics fantastic'),"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
famouse  fabrics  fantastic
```

Comment: The result is now "famous phone". But i want to remove also phone. Also all words starting with fa-anytext and the word fa.