# replace some words from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I want to remove some words from a string:

1. the word: **fa**
2. the word: **livicon**
3. all words starting with **fa-** (in this case fa-word and fa-word-small, but this words can also be different. For example fa-user)

**String:**

```
fa fa-word livicon fa-word-small fantastic
```

**Output should be**

```
fantastic
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Also what is the difference to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28751418/3933332 ?

Comment: The difference to this question is, that I want to replace the word livicon too. So I think it was better to start a new question. Sorry, but I am a new user here. preg_replace is very hard for a newbird.  I try to learn just.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regular expression that uses [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and an optional grouping for the `-word-etc` parts of your prefixed strings. The below would suffice ...

```
$str = 'fa fa-word livicon fa-word-small fantastic';
$str = preg_replace('~\b(?:fa(?:-\w+)*|livicon)\b~', '', $str);
echo trim($str); //=> "fantastic"
```